# date stored in seperate strings, how to change it to be in one string in the array CAKEPHP

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, date, cakephp-2.0

This is my first CakePhp project and i have an issue with dates..

my database as one field for the date of birth (dob) so when the user logs in the date array is stored like `[dob] => 1992-04-24` but when they change their date it makes it to `[dob] => Array ( [month] => 04 [day] => 24 [year] => 1992 )`

I think its to do with when with either my edit field or model, but i cannot figure it out. so here is the model:

```
<?php

App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');

/**
 * User Model
 *
 * @property Group $Group
 */
class User extends AppModel {

    public $validationDomain = 'validation';

    public $belongsTo = array('Group');
    public $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'requester'));

    public function parentNode() {
        if (!$this->id && empty($this->data)) {
            return null;
        }
        if (isset($this->data['User']['group_id'])) {
            $groupId = $this->data['User']['group_id'];
        } else {
            $groupId = $this->field('group_id');
        }
        if (!$groupId) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return array('Group' => array('id' => $groupId));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Validation rules
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $validate = array(
        'username' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
            ),
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
            ),
        ),
        'name' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Your name is required'
            )
        ),
        'dob' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'please enter your date of birth'
             )
        ),
            'group_id' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),
        )
    ),
    );

    public function bindNode($user) {
        return array('model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => $user['User']['group_id']);
    }

    public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Here is the edit field:

```
<div class="edit user form">
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'useredit'));
echo $this->Form->input('id', array('type' => 'hidden'));
echo $this->Form->input('username', array('label' => __('Username', true), 'value' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.username')));
echo $this->Form->input('password', array('label' => __('Password', true), 'value' => ''));
echo $this->Form->input('name', array('label' => __('Name', true), 'value' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.name')));
echo $this->Form->input('dob', array ('label' => __('Date Of Birth', true) 
                                        , 'value' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.dob')
                                        , 'dateFormat' => 'YMD'
                                        , 'minYear' => date('Y') - 90
                                        , 'maxYear' => date('Y') - 0));
echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit'));
?>
</div>
```

And just in case you want the debugger report here it is:

```
array(
    'User' => array(
        'password' => '*****',
        'id' => '2',
        'username' => 'iwanjones',
        'name' => 'Iwan',
        'dob' => array(
            'year' => '2013',
            'month' => '03',
            'day' => '26'
        ),
    )
)
```

i would like the debugger to save the array as

```
array(
    'User' => array(
        'password' => '*****',
        'id' => '2',
        'username' => 'iwanjones',
        'name' => 'Iwan',
        'dob' => '2013/03/26'
        ),
    )
)
```

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing? This is the default way that Cake saves `DATE` and `DATETIME` fields to a database. It seperates all the inputs into different array keys, but will save it properly to your database. Doing a find/read will just return the raw value that is stored.

Comment: well i want the date to be stored as one string in the array, not separated by date, month and year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, according to your comment, you would need to add a beforeSave method to your User model that molds the date back into a single string:

```
function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    // Convert the dob back to a single string
    if (!empty($this->data[$this->alias]['dob'])) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['dob'] = implode('-',
            $this->data[$this->alias]['dob']['year'],
            $this->data[$this->alias]['dob']['month'],
            $this->data[$this->alias]['dob']['day']
        );
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> "well i want the date to be stored as one string in the array, not
>   separated by date, month and year"

There is no problem.  It stores it like that intentionally per CakePHP, but will save correctly in a single date field.